# Normalizr + Redux - Updating a property of a single entity

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

I am building a music player app and I'm using a REST API to fetch tracks from various endpoints (playlists, tracks posted by a certain user, etc.)

I'm using redux and normalizr to manage my state. I've created a `tracks` entity which I'm using to map a `track` object and their ids.

In short my state looks a bit like this:

```
{
  playlists: {
    123: { id: 123, name: 'foo', tracks: [1, 2, 3] }
  },
  users: {
    me: { name: 'Niek', tracks: [2, 3] },
  },
  entities: {
    tracks: {
      1: { name: 'bar', user_favorited: false, ... },
      2: { name: 'foo', user_favorited: false, ... },
      3: { name: 'bar', user_favorited: true, ... }
    }
  }
}
```

This is working great for me so far. But now I'm building the functionality to toggle the `favorite` status of a track, by calling another API endpoint.

This endpoint does not include the entire `track` resource in the response, but I do want to update the `user_favorited` property of a single `track` entity after the API call is successful.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

As a workaround I'm now fetching the entire `track` entity again from another endpoint after the `user_favorited` endpoint call was successful, but I was hoping to find an elegant solution where this isn't necessary.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Will propose two solutions:

1. **Refetch the data.**
2. **Change the entities.**

One way to do this is would be to create an entities reducer like this:

```js
const tracksReducer = (state, action) => {
    // Change the tracks
}

const entitiesReducer = (state, action) => {
    let _state = state;

    // Store all entities
    if (action.payload && action.payload.entities) {
        _state = merge({}, state, action.payload.entities);
    }

    return combineReducers({
        tracks: tracksReducer,
    })(_state, action);
};

export default { entities: entitiesReducer };
```

<sub>* Code above uses `merge` from lodash and `combineReducers` from redux</sub>

---

> Lately I've been also thinking about another structure completely, but haven't tested it nor found anybody else sharing their experiences with it. The idea would be do remove the first level "entities" completely and storing them under the corresponding key. Theoretically it seems to make sense when we start to make changes to entities and would be easier to keep all similar reducers, selectors etc. in a single place.

```js
{
    tracks: {
        entities: {
            1: { name: 'bar', user_favorited: false, ... },
            2: { name: 'foo', user_favorited: false, ... },
            3: { name: 'bar', user_favorited: true, ... }
        },
        top3: [1, 2, 3],
        somethingAboutTracks: true
    },
    users: {
        entities: {},
        me: { name: 'Niek', tracks: [2, 3] }
    },
    playlists: {
        entities: {
            123: { id: 123, name: 'foo', tracks: [1, 2, 3] }
        }
    }
}
```